# Material UI Grid Items not taking full width available

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, styling

I am using a nested Grid system in Material UI and the Grid items are only taking a fixed width and are leaving some space. And when that fixed space gets exhausted, The components instead of squeezing their internal free, space, they break the UI.

See the screenshots for clarity (All screenshots taken in Google Chrome).

[Outer Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKpap.png)

[Outer Grid Item 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rISD9.png)    [Outer Grid Item 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amSJp.png)

[Inner Grid System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bs2lV.png)

[Now we start to squeeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfzwv.png)

[UI breaks... But the second component still has the same width as before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pOhV.png)

Snippet for the outer Grid

```
<Grid container justifyContent="space-evenly" direction={isMd ? "row" : "column"}>
          <Grid item sx={{ minWidth: "300px" }}>
            <Typography>Component coming soon</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item component={Footer2}></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Snippet for the Inner Grid

```
        <Grid
          container
          justifyContent="space-evenly"
          direction={isMd ? "row" : "column"}
          gap={6}
        >
          <Grid item links={["COMPANY", "About", "Experts and Spokesmodels"]}>
            <Listings
              links={["COMPANY", "About", "Experts and Spokesmodels"]}
            ></Listings>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Listings
              links={[
                "CUSTOMER SERVICE",
                "Contact Us",
                "My Account",
                "Store Locator",
                "Redeem Rewards"
              ]}
            ></Listings>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Listings
              links={[
                "MORE TO EXPLORE",
                "Beauty Magazine",
                "Tools and Consultations",
                "Offers",
                "#LorealParis"
              ]}
            ></Listings>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

[SandBox link](https://r2zw8.csb.app)

Comment: Hey Julia, welcome! 

Can you update your question to include the relevant code snippets (probably the main Grid component and the child/children)? I see you have a Sandbox link, but I suspect you'll get more replies if the code is directly visible in the question.

Comment: Done.... Please answer or upvote so that it can reach a wider audience

Answer (score 0):

[Fixed variant](https://codesandbox.io/s/justifycontent-material-demo-fixed-ssm0u?file=/FooterP2.js:405-642)

Just in FooterP2.js delete gap props of Grid component, add CSS rules for ScopedCssBaseline and set maxWidth for element (I set 800px for example).

```
<ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <ScopedCssBaseline 
      style={{ flex: "1 1 auto", maxWidth: "800px" }}>
        <Grid
          container
          justifyContent="space-evenly"
          direction={isMd ? "row" : "column"}
        >
```